# hreflang issue from webmaster tools

Tags: html, seo, google-search-console, hreflang

So I use href lang ONLY on my INDEX page, like this:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="https://example.com" hreflang="x-default" />
```

But I keep getting these errors in google webmaster tools

> Google has detected that some pages on your site have implemented the
>   rel-alternate-hreflang tag incorrectly. In particular, there seems to
>   be a problem with incorrect language and region codes, or incorrect
>   bi-directional linking (if page A links with hreflang to page B, there
>   must be a link back from B to A as well). Google uses the hreflang
>   attributes to serve the correct language or regional URL to the right
>   users in search results. Until you correct the errors on the hreflang
>   links, your website will not benefit from additional language or
>   region targeting.

I don't understand why? I searched alot and can't seem to find an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have any pages with locales listed, then just use **x** instead of x-default (or indeed the language-code, e.g. en/de etc.)

Usually you would use `hreflang=x-default` in a a **set** like this (note the several locales indicated in the alternate pages)

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="http://www.example.com/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-gb" href="http://en-gb.example.com/page.html" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-us" href="http://en-us.example.com/page.html" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://en.example.com/page.html" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="http://de.example.com/seite.html"/>
```

Footnote: I found a handy hreflang generator tool [here](http://www.aleydasolis.com/en/international-seo-tools/hreflang-tags-generator/)

Answer (score 0):

Hreflang is used when you have content in multiple languages. From your question it looks like you don't really have versions of that page in other languages. So don't use hreflang. Remove that `<link>` tag.